# Spark Streaming: How to get the count of the timestamps for a day?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Reading the streaming from a kafka topic where data has timestamp. This data can have future or past timestamps as well.
Is there way to get the count of the data coming in for a day?
I tried to cast the `timestamp` into `date` and then aggregated on the `date` and get the `sum` as the `count`. It doesn't seem to work.

```
sourceDataset
                .withWatermark("timestamp", watermarkInterval)
                .select(
                        col("timestamp").cast("date")
                )
                .groupBy(
                        functions.window(col("date"), windowInterval)
                ).sum().as("count")
                ;
```

Comment: Would you be able to share an input/output sample? It might just make it easier to think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use a javapairdstream and set the date as key for and value as 1.Now reduce by key can be used to count number of occurrences. This is applicable if you are trying to get the number in  a micro batch